# Light and Dark Mode in Chart.js Problems

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js, visual-web-developer

So, basically I have a light and dark mode, that works with a simple button and this changes the mode form light to dark and chart.js takes its value from a CSS variable which changes in light and dark mode.

I get the root element in this code section, and than it is passed into the Chart.

```
// Get the root element
var r = document.querySelector(':root');
var rs = getComputedStyle(r);
```

I cannot get the chart labels to change when the mode changes; the variables come in through rs.getPropertyValue and I cannot get the chart to effectively change colors even with these variables?  I think it is most likely due to the fact Chart.js doesn't like after it is initially rendered.

```
// format the dates using Moment.js and store them in an array
const labels = dates.map(date => moment(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A'));
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Set up the Chart.js chart
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        //labels: {{ labels|tojson }},
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Solar Power (W)',
          data: {{ solarPower|tojson }},
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(251, 99, 88, 0.2)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(251, 99, 88, 1)',
          borderWidth: 1
        }, {
          label: 'Battery Voltage (V)',
          data: {{ batteryVoltage|tojson }},
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(96, 177, 237, 0.2)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(96, 177, 237, 1)',
          borderWidth: 1
        }, {
          label: 'Load Power (W)',
          data: {{ batteryVoltage|tojson }},
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(56, 218, 91, 0.2)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(56, 218, 91, 1)',
          borderWidth: 1,
          fontColor: 'white'
        }, {
          label: 'Solar Voltage (V)',
          data: {{ solarVoltage|tojson }},
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(250, 112, 225, 0.2)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(250, 112, 225, 1)',
          borderWidth: 1
        }, {
          label: 'Solar Current (A)',
          data: {{ solarCurrent|tojson }},
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(77,219,255, 0.2)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(77,219,255, 1)',
          borderWidth: 1,
          color: rs.getPropertyValue('--app-content-main-color')
        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: 'Date and Time',
              fontSize:14,
              fontColor: rs.getPropertyValue('--app-content-main-color')
            },
            ticks: {
              fontColor: rs.getPropertyValue('--app-content-main-color'),
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: 'Values',
              fontSize:14,
              fontColor: rs.getPropertyValue('--app-content-main-color')
            },
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              fontColor: rs.getPropertyValue('--app-content-main-color')
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    });
```

The code above is what I have tried, but